# How to fix blank output? PHP Script

Tags: php, arrays, input, output

Solved the issue:
All I needed to do is to add a seperator to fgetcsv
`while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($ih,10000,';')))`

We receive a file from our supplier. The file has 60k rows and we need to somehow filter this file automatically.

The csv file has 3 columns: SKU, Category, Price.
I have filtered this file using excel and I see that we only need like 700 products from this file. All of them have the same category 'Injectors'

I have written a php script, but it gives me a blank output. Can someone explain what is wrong with my code?

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'); 
$input = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Data.csv';
$output = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Data_changed.csv';
$myfile = fopen("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\data_log.txt", "w") or die("Something wrong with this file.");
$vname='The process was successful: '.date('Y-m-d').' day';
fwrite($myfile, $vname);
fclose($myfile);
$injector = "Injector";
if (false !== ($ih = fopen($input, 'r'))) {
    $oh = fopen($output, 'w');

    while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($ih))) {

if (strpos($data[1], $injector) !== false) {

        // this is where you build your new row
        $outputData = array($data[0], $data[1], $data[2]);
        fputcsv($oh, $outputData);


    }
    }

    fclose($ih);
    fclose($oh);
}
?>
```

The expected output is 700 filtered products.

This is how a csv file looks like:

[Sample data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVfCF.png)

Basically, what I want is to make a script which finds all the rows which contain a text "Injector" in the second column.

Also to mention: the original file comes with semicolon as a seperator.
The default seperator for the windows is comma.

Comment: _"The excel file"_ - Did you mean csv-file, or is there an actual Excel file?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, yes, csv file

Comment: @Sigitas your "yes" does which question answer? It's a csv or Excel?

Comment: @user2342558 - My first question was just if they meant a csv-file. I think they answered that at the same time I edited the comment to include the _"or..."_ so I'm pretty sure they mean yes to it being csv. My bad...

Comment: @user2342558, it's a csv file.

Comment: @Sigitas so edit your question replacing "excel" with "csv"...

Comment: You should also edit your question to include some sample data from the csv since we have _no clue_ what it looks like. You should also clarify what condition you want to filter it on. You're basically asking us to help you filter some unknown data using some unknown criteria. Include what debugging you've done and your conclusion.

Comment: @user2342558, just did it.

Comment: See also: [How can I get useful error messages in PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/845021)

Comment: Just to make 100% certain *"I have written a php script, but it gives me a blank output."* ... you're referring to output in the new CSV right (or data_log.txt)? **Not** on the screen (since there's no code here to output anything to the screen)...

Comment: yes, output in the new csv file.

Comment: Please show us the results of your debugging - e.g. does your code pass this condition: `if (strpos($data[1], $injector) !== false) {` - or does it fail earlier?

Answer (score 0):

If you opened the file in Excel, make sure the .csv if comma separated and not semicolon separated.

edit: you can check this by opening the file in a text editor like notepad/notepad++.

Comment: the original file comes with semicolon as a seperator. The default seperator for the windows is comma.
Maybe this is a problem? Because 'display_error on"  does not show any problems.

Comment: Yes, this will cause your whole line to be put in `$data[0]`. You can pass the separator in `fgetcsv` as third parameter. 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php